# Can I get an Android device ID through a mobile website?

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier, telephony, mac-address

Is it possible to get a device's telephony ID, MAC Address, serial number, and/or Android ID through a mobile website?

That is, not through a downloadable app, but through a link that the user goes to in the browser on their mobile device?

If so, how?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, mostly due to privacy/tracking reasons. The best you could do is get the UserAgent

Comment: What is the UserAgent? Is that available via an app as well? Basically, I need a way to get the same unique(ish) identifier via website and via app.

Comment: For the website, you could perhaps use the IP address. At any given instance, it is unique. However, it will change everytime the user connects to a different network, or restarts his/her current network.

Comment: The user agent tells you what kind of browser/device they are viewing the page with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Comment: @Kalina I know this is an extremely old question, but is there any way of doing this now? This is something that I'd like to use to stitch user journeys across a website and an app for non-logged-in users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Even for native apps, device identity information is safeguarded behind the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.

As websites cannot request permissions, you cannot retrieve this information outside of an app.

Comment: Isn't Telephony the only ID that requires `READ_PHONE_STATE`?

Comment: IMEI/ESN, and the WiFi/BlueTooth MAC addresses require the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission

Comment: Is there a citation for this I can use as a source?

Answer (score 1):

You said you need a unique(ish) ID on a website.

Look into UserAgents: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent which will tell you what kind of device/browser is viewing your webpage

And you can also retrieve the IP address of the user, which may change in future requests to your website.

You could also attempt to store a cookie, but the user may delete their cookies at any time.

For specifics on how to get these, it depends on what your web site is built with.

Comment: Thanks! IP address and cookies are out, because I need a more persistent identifier that is also consistent between the mobile app and the mobile website. I will look into UserAgents.

Comment: @TheBeatlemaniac Just note that a UserAgent will look something like this: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; en-us; SCH-I535 4G Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30;` you could possibly have multiple users with the same UserAgent if they use the same phone and browser and OS